# What happens programmatically when you switch browser tabs?

Tags: events, google-chrome, browser, fancybox

I'm having a weird issue with fancybox in chrome where my scrollbar isn't appearing until I switch to another chrome tab and switch back. I'll figure it out myself -- I'd just like to get to a starting point by knowing, in as specific a sense as possible, what exactly happens when your browser switches tabs?

---

Things like:

1. What loses/gains focus?
2. Any other events fired off?
3. How is chrome different from other browsers in this sense?

---

**Sorry if this question is a bit open ended -- I did my best to qualify it in a way that made it possible to be answered concretely.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox scrollbar is playing games with me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464493/fancybox-scrollbar-is-playing-games-with-me)

Comment: this question (as well as the other that was closed) is difficult to answer without your code or a link to a page with the issue. The behavior you describe may have many causes from js errors, css rules, lack of `DOCTYPE`, etc. the question is vague so does the answer.

Comment: in an effort to reply, what happens when you switch tabs?  : jQuery hides all containers (it's likely each tab is a `div` or section) and shows only the container that matches the index of the corresponding tab ... so it's just a hide and show operation.

Comment: @JFK I was actually trying to make this question a standalone, totally different question as opposed to the other one. I don't want to know anything specific to my code, or jquery, or fancybox -- I just want to know what browsers do when the tab is changed. What events are fired, etc.

Comment: @JFK I think he means browser tabs...

Comment: I'd guess that the browser fires onblur on whatever's focused and that bubbles up. Maybe it's just the browser redrawing the content.

Comment: @gengkev : you are right ... the question is confusing so I guess I misread it, my bad. In this case I think is a specific issue of the OP's page (maybe a css conflict) that has nothing to do with fancybox or the browser tab (but difficult to know without code or a link to such page)

Comment: @JFK you're focusing too much on my other question. I didn't want any answers as to why my fancybox wasn't working -- I just wanted to know what happens when you switch browser tabs